# Flutter app is experiencing crashes on Android 13 and above when attempting to select an image using the image_picker

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-image-picker

My Flutter app is experiencing crashes on Android 13 and above when attempting to select an image using the image_picker plugin. The application functions correctly on Android 12 and below. The error message displayed simply states 'Lost Device Connection.'

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try following methods (note : these are not steps)

1. Make sure you have necessary permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

   If not try adding this permissions

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```
2. Update or downgrade `image_picker` plugin
3. If this happening after flutter sdk update then downgrade sdk
4. Enable multidex in app/build.gradle

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       .......
       minSdkVersion 21
       targetSdkVersion 28 
       multiDexEnabled true
       .......
    }

   dependencies {
       .....
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
       compile  'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
   ```